# Parsing unicode emoji text file using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, emoji

The Unicode organisation provides a text file which contains categorisation and name details for emojis.

The latest version is available here:
http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/5.0/emoji-test.txt

Each emoji belongs to one of 8 broad `Groups`and each `Group` is then split out into a number of subgroups - for example - the subgroups for the `Animals & Nature` group are listed below:

```
# group: Smileys & People
# group: Animals & Nature

    # subgroup: animal-mammal
    # subgroup: animal-bird
    # subgroup: animal-amphibian
    # subgroup: animal-reptile
    # subgroup: animal-marine
    # subgroup: animal-bug
    # subgroup: plant-flower
    # subgroup: plant-other

# group: Food & Drink
# group: Travel & Places
# group: Activities
# group: Objects
# group: Symbols
# group: Flags
```

Then the emojis in each subgroup are listed against each subgroup - for example, for the `animal-bird` subgroup, these emojis are listed:

```
1F983                                      ; fully-qualified     #  turkey
1F414                                      ; fully-qualified     #  chicken
1F413                                      ; fully-qualified     #  rooster
1F423                                      ; fully-qualified     #  hatching chick
1F424                                      ; fully-qualified     #  baby chick
1F425                                      ; fully-qualified     #  front-facing baby chick
1F426                                      ; fully-qualified     #  bird
1F427                                      ; fully-qualified     #  penguin
1F54A FE0F                                 ; fully-qualified     # ️ dove
1F54A                                      ; non-fully-qualified #  dove
1F985                                      ; fully-qualified     #  eagle
1F986                                      ; fully-qualified     #  duck
1F989                                      ; fully-qualified     #  owl
```

Each Emoji therefore has the following attributes - taking the `turkey` emoji as an example:

- Group: Animals & Nature
- Subgroup: animal-reptile
- Name: 1F983
- Status: fully-qualified
- Emoji:
- Description: turkey

I have a MySQL table which I'd like to store the emoji details in:

```
CREATE TABLE `xx_emoji` (
  `fld_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fld_group` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fld_cat` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `fld_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `fld_status` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `fld_emoji` varbinary(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fld_description` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fld_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

I could manually go through the text file and save the details into the MySQL table one at a time, so I'd get data like this in the table - e.g.

[image: Screenshot from SQLyog]

However, I wondered if it would be possible to parse through the text file using PHP instead?

I guess it'd need to have a series of nested loops:

```
foreach group {
    foreach subgroup {
        loop through emoji list and save into MySQL table...
            group
            subgroup
            name
            status
            emoji
            description
        end loop
    }
}
```

I realise that's just a very basic outline, and I'm sorry for asking such a broad question.

I have looked on the unicode website to see if the emoji data is available in any other format which is more useful, like XML or JSON, but I cannot find anything, and can only see this for the current emoji version:

https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/5.0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shes not very pretty, and may break if they change the format, but here you go, at least it points you in the right direction :p

```
<?php
if (!file_exists('emoji-test.txt')) {
    file_put_contents('emoji-test.txt', file_get_contents('http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/5.0/emoji-test.txt'));
}

// break into blocks
$blocks = explode(PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL, file_get_contents('emoji-test.txt'));

// unset header
unset($blocks[0]);

$emoji = [];

foreach ($blocks as $chunk) {
    $top = explode(PHP_EOL, $chunk)[0];

    if (substr($top, 0, strlen('# group:')) == '# group:') {
        $group = trim(str_replace('# group:', '', $top));
    } elseif (substr($top, 0, strlen('# subgroup:')) == '# subgroup:') {

        $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $chunk);
        unset($lines[0]);

        foreach ($lines as $line) {

            $subgroup = trim(str_replace('# subgroup:', '', $top));

            $linegroup = explode(';', $line);

            $parts = explode('#', $linegroup[1]);

            $icon = explode(' ', trim($parts[1]), 2);

            $emoji[$group][$subgroup][] = [
                'group' => trim($group),
                'subgroup' => $subgroup,
                'name' => trim($linegroup[0]),
                'status' => trim($parts[0]),
                'emoji' => trim($icon[0]),
                'description' => trim($icon[1]),
            ];
        }
    }
}

print_r($emoji);
```

Output looks like the following, group and then subgroup nested, which you can then easily loop over and insert into your database.

```
Array
(
    [Smileys & People] => Array
        (
            [face-positive] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [group] => Smileys & People
                            [subgroup] => face-positive
                            [name] => 1F600
                            [status] => fully-qualified
                            [emoji] => 
                            [description] => grinning face
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [group] => Smileys & People
                            [subgroup] => face-positive
                            [name] => 1F601
                            [status] => fully-qualified
                            [emoji] => 
                            [description] => beaming face with smiling eyes
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [group] => Smileys & People
                            [subgroup] => face-positive
                            [name] => 1F602
                            [status] => fully-qualified
                            [emoji] => 
                            [description] => face with tears of joy
                        )
 ...snip
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much Lawrence - you're so kind to have done that. I really appreciate it. I saw your solution is on Github too, good idea :-)

Answer (score 0):

Further to Lawrence's very helpful answer, I'm adding an answer here, showing how I was able to use the code to access the 6 attributes for each emoji, so I could load them into a MySQL table:

```
...
foreach ($blocks as $chunk) {
    $top = explode(PHP_EOL, $chunk)[0];
    if (substr($top, 0, strlen('# group:')) == '# group:') {
        $group = trim(str_replace('# group:', '', $top));
    } elseif (substr($top, 0, strlen('# subgroup:')) == '# subgroup:') {
        $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $chunk);
        unset($lines[0]);
        foreach ($lines as $line) {
            
            $subgroup = trim(str_replace('# subgroup:', '', $top));
            $linegroup = explode(';', $line);
            $parts = explode('#', $linegroup[1]);
            $icon = explode(' ', trim($parts[1]), 2);
            
            $var_group =        trim($group);
            $var_sub_group =    trim($subgroup);
            $var_name =         trim($linegroup[0]);
            $var_status =       trim($parts[0]);
            $var_emoji =        trim($icon[0]);
            $var_description =  trim($icon[1]);
            
    /*$emoji[$group][$subgroup][] = [
        'group' => trim($group),
        'subgroup' => $subgroup,
        'name' => trim($linegroup[0]),
        'status' => trim($parts[0]),
        'emoji' => trim($icon[0]),
        'description' => trim($icon[1]),
    ];*/

     $sql = "INSERT INTO xx_emoji (fld_group
                                 , fld_sub_group
                                 , fld_name
                                 , fld_status
                                 , fld_emoji
                                 , fld_description) 
                           VALUES (:var_group
                                 , :var_sub_group
                                 , :var_name
                                 , :var_status
                                 , :var_emoji
                                 , :var_description)";

    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindParam(':var_group', $var_group);
    $stmt->bindParam(':var_sub_group', $var_sub_group);
    $stmt->bindParam(':var_name', $var_name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':var_status', $var_status);
    $stmt->bindParam(':var_emoji', $var_emoji);
    $stmt->bindParam(':var_description', $var_description);

    $stmt->execute();
        }
    }
}
```

Update 26-DEC-2020 - Lawrence has updated his Github code to work with Unicode 13, here: https://github.com/lcherone/emoji-parse

Additionally, Lawrence's github code has solution for loading the data into MySQL: https://github.com/lcherone/emoji-parse/blob/master/index.php, which contains an include pointing to '[parse.php](https://github.com/lcherone/emoji-parse/blob/master/parse.php)'.